# WSO2 ESB API configuration to send same post request to different Rest services

Tags: wso2-esb

I need to send a post request to different REST services, below is the complete requirement.
I am using REST API configuration of WSO2 ESB
First I need to post a request to one service and based on successful posting then need to post this same to another service. But I need to obtain the response from first service and send it to fronend. But I do not need to obtain the response from second service.

Please find the API configuration below and help me.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" context="/test">
   <resource methods="POST DELETE PUT GET">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Message Flow" value="Roovershof Plant Search API - IN"></property>
            <property name="HTTP_METHOD IS###########" expression="$axis2:HTTP_METHOD"></property>
            <property name="ip address" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"></property>
            <property name="Authorization" expression="get-property('transport','Authorization')"></property>
         </log>
         <property name="TIME_IN" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="default" type="LONG"></property>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="service1"></address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Request Method :" expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_METHOD')"></property>
         </log>
         <filter source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')" regex="201">
            <then>
            <clone continueParent="true">
   <target>
      <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"></property>
               <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
               <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2"></property>
               <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
               <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="servicr2"></address>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
   </target>
   <target sequence="magento" />
</clone>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your synapse configuration does not match your statement. You have to preserve the original message using [enrich mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Enrich+Mediator) and then make use the [call mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Call+Mediator) for your first endpoint invocation.

Then based on the results, you send the response back to your client and do the send call by reloading the message from the preservation.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestApi" context="/TestContext">
   <resource methods="POST GET">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Message Flow" value="Roovershof Plant Search API - IN"></property>
            <property name="HTTP_METHOD IS###########" expression="$axis2:HTTP_METHOD"></property>
            <property name="ip address" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"></property>
            <property name="Authorization" expression="get-property('transport','Authorization')"></property>
         </log>
         <property name="TIME_IN" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="default" type="LONG"></property>

         <enrich>
            <source type="body" clone="true"></source>
            <target type="property" property="INIT_MSG_PAYLOAD"></target>
         </enrich>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="service1"></address>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <filter source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')" regex="201">
            <then>
               <clone continueParent="true">
                  <target>
                     <sequence>
                        <respond></respond>
                     </sequence>
                  </target>
                  <target>
                     <sequence>
                        <enrich>
                           <source type="property" clone="true" property="INIT_MSG_PAYLOAD"></source>
                           <target type="body"></target>
                        </enrich>
                        <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"></property>
                        <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
                        <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2"></property>
                        <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
                        <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
                        <send>
                           <endpoint>
                              <address uri="servicr2"></address>
                           </endpoint>
                        </send>
                     </sequence>
                  </target>
               </clone>
            </then>
            <else>
               <respond/>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```